# ASP.NET - Virtual PC

Tags: asp.net, vpc

I have created an ASP.NET application on my local machine. In order to test this application in IE 6, I have created a VPC. I am trying to connect to this web application through the VPC. However, I cannot connect to it. I can however connect to the internet.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you ping from the virtual PC? If not, you have network configuration issues.

Otherwise, check firewalls, and make sure that port 80 is open and sending traffic to IIS.

Comment: I can ping from the Virtual PC. I have also verified that port 80 and my development port (in this case 3054) is open. I still cannot run my app though.

Comment: The next thing to try is to telnet from the virtual PC to port 80 on the web server. If telnet can't get there, you'll get an error. If it appears to hang (no response), then telnet successfully connected to the port.

Comment: it says "could not open connection to the host, on port 80: connect failed"

Answer (score 0):

there are many possibilities. first I'd consider would be any firewall rules on the ASP.NET side preventing incoming HTTP connections.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL you are using to go to your site?  If you are using localhost, you will need to change that to the actual IP address of your development machine, as localhost on the Virtual PC image will be a different IP address than localhost on the development machine.

Comment: I'm using the ip address of my host: 192.168.1.102